# How to find the max value of multiple columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the maximum value of multiple columns in a Spark dataframe. Each Column has a value of double type.

The dataframe is like:

```scala
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|Name | A | B  | C | D |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|Alex |5.1|-6.2|  7|  8|
|John |  7| 8.3|  1|  2|
|Alice|  5|  46|  3|  2|
|Mark |-20| -11|-22| -5|
+-----+---+----+---+---+
```

The expectation is:

```
+-----+---+----+---+---+----------+
|Name | A | B  | C | D | MaxValue |
+-----+---+----+---+---+----------+
|Alex |5.1|-6.2|  7|  8|     8    |
|John |  7| 8.3|  1|  2|     8.3  | 
|Alice|  5|  46|  3|  2|     46   |
|Mark |-20| -11|-22| -5|     -5   |
+-----+---+----+---+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 24):

You could apply [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@greatest(columnName:String,columnNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to the list of numeric columns, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("Alex", 5.1, -6.2, 7.0, 8.0),
  ("John", 7.0, 8.3, 1.0, 2.0),
  ("Alice", 5.0, 46.0, 3.0, 2.0),
  ("Mark", -20.0, -11.0, -22.0, -5.0),
).toDF("Name", "A", "B", "C", "D")

val numCols = df.columns.tail  // Apply suitable filtering as needed (*)

df.withColumn("MaxValue", greatest(numCols.head, numCols.tail: _*)).
  show
// +-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
// | Name|    A|    B|    C|   D|MaxValue|
// +-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
// | Alex|  5.1| -6.2|  7.0| 8.0|     8.0|
// | John|  7.0|  8.3|  1.0| 2.0|     8.3|
// |Alice|  5.0| 46.0|  3.0| 2.0|    46.0|
// | Mark|-20.0|-11.0|-22.0|-5.0|    -5.0|
// +-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
```

(*) For example, to filter for all top-level `DoubleType` columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val numCols = df.schema.fields.collect{
  case StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _) => name
}
```

If you're on `Spark 2.4+`, an alternative would be to use [`array_max`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array_max(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), although it would involve an additional step of transformation in this case:

```
df.withColumn("MaxValue", array_max(array(numCols.map(col): _*)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if you can show how dynamically specify the indices/name  of the columns which we want to find their max. Also, when the number of the selected column is one, how we can handle it.

Comment: @user2967251, not sure I completely understand your questions.  Method `greatest` computes max value column-wise hence expects at least 2 columns.  You could use `when/otherwise` to conditionally handle the 1-column case based on size of `numCols`.  In any case, if you have a more specific filtering requirement, I would suggest that you post a separate question that includes the filtering specifics, a minuscule sample dataset, and the problem you encounter when trying to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

First, I replicated your df:

```scala
scala> df.show
```

```
+-----+---+----+---+---+
| Name|  A|   B|  C|  D|
+-----+---+----+---+---+
| Alex|5.1|-6.2|  7|  8|
| John|  7| 8.3|  1|  2|
|Alice|  5|  46|  3|  2|
| Mark|-20| -11|-22| -5|
+-----+---+----+---+---+
```

Then I converted it into an RDD and transformed it at the row level:

```scala
import scala.math.max
case class MyData(Name: String, A: Double, B: Double, C: Double, D: Double, MaxValue: Double)
val maxDF = df.rdd.map(row => {
val a = row(1).toString.toDouble
val b = row(2).toString.toDouble
val c = row(3).toString.toDouble
val d = row(4).toString.toDouble
new MyData(row(0).toString, a, b, c, d, max(max(a, b), max(c, d)))
}).toDF
```

Here is the final output:

```scala
maxDF.show
```

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
| Name|    A|    B|    C|   D|MaxValue|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
| Alex|  5.1| -6.2|  7.0| 8.0|     8.0|
| John|  7.0|  8.3|  1.0| 2.0|     8.3|
|Alice|  5.0| 46.0|  3.0| 2.0|    46.0|
| Mark|-20.0|-11.0|-22.0|-5.0|    -5.0|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+--------+
```

Comment: How does this solution can be scaled for multi-million row dataframe? The tables in the question are just for illustration of problem. Please provide a solution for very large number of rows in the dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: @user2967251 why sould it not scale? It may not scale for number of columns

Comment: It does scale, and produces the correct answer. I'm not sure why I was downvoted for this solution. It is not as concise as the accepted answer but is still a valid solution.