# How to get max value of few columns and creating a new column in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

[image]

I need to iterate through item_1 to item_3 and then get the max value of the row and create a new column called item.

output should look like below:

[image]

What function should we use here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post spark questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the max value of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531778/how-to-find-the-max-value-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

the function you are looking for is called [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest)

```py
df.withColumn(
    "item",
    greatest("item_1","item_2","item_3")
)
```

Comment: is there any way we can do "grep" function. Like get all the columns with names "item_" and then perform greatest function?there are a lot of colunmns with item name on it

Comment: @NickRyan are you familiar with Python ? `a = [i for i in df.columns if "item_" in i]` and `greatest(*a)`