# Replace date value in pyspark by maximum of two column

Tags: pyspark

I'm using pyspark 3.0.1. I have a dataframe df with following details

```
ID  Class dateEnrolled dateStarted
32   1     2016-01-09   2016-01-26
25   1     2016-01-09   2016-01-10
33   1     2016-01-16   2016-01-05
```

I need to replace dateEnrolled my latest of two date field & my data should look like

```
ID  Class dateEnrolled dateStarted
32   1     2016-01-26   2016-01-26
25   1     2016-01-10   2016-01-10
33   1     2016-01-16   2016-01-05
```

Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the max value of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531778/how-to-find-the-max-value-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `greatest`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('dateEnrolled', F.greatest('dateEnrolled', 'dateStarted'))
```